# FIFO Depth Calculation

Tags: fifo, soc, digital-design

I have 2 blocks, out of which block_A is writing and block_B is reading.

Writing configurations : 3 writes per 5 clocks,
Reading configurations : 30 reads per 50 clocks

What is the required FIFO depth in order to avoid FIFO underflow/overflow?
It is provided that both the FIFOs are working at same frequency.

IF we calculate the frequency then, it would be 3/5 for both the Blocks. But then again this frequency of 3/5 is an average frequency.
So I am not sure how to calculate the FIFO depth.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear to me from your description if this a fixed pattern, or some estimation over a very long period of time for one of the sides.

If it's guaranteed that we will have 3 writes per 5 cycles, and 30 reads per 50 cycles, then you can calculate the needed buffer depth using the equation:

```
FifoDepth = BW*LatencyFromPushToPop
```

In your case:

```
BW = 3/5   //This is the BW that you want to pass through the FIFO. 
LatencyFromPushToPop = (50-30) = 20 cycles //you must add to this number the actual latency of the FIFO (1, 2 cycles?), which I am not considering here
```

From this equation you get that the minimal FIFO depth to avoid write backpressure, is:

```
 3 / 5 * 20 = 12.
```

You can also get to it by trying to simulate the worst case scenario of the FIFO fill level:

1. Block B starts reading only after 20 cycles.
2. Block A writes as much as it can during those 20 cycles.

Block A will write during 20 cycles at most 20 / 5 * 3 = 12 entries.

When block B will start reading it will read 30 entries straight.
During those 30 cycles, block A will write at most 30 / 5 * 3 = extra 18 entries.

Since block B will read during those 30 cycles 30 entries, which are exactly 12+18 entries, the FIFO will be emptied and will not cross the number 12 in its fill level (and we are back to the square one).

**Note1:**

Not sure I understand what you mean by underflow. By definition block A sends data only 3/5 of the time, so there must be some cycles where there is nothing to read from the FIFO.
If there is nothing to read from the FIFO, block B should not pop anything.

**Note2:**

If one of the sides average BW is an estimation over a long period of time, then it really depends on the burstiness of the traffic.

A good example for it is if a block writes 50% of the time over a period of 1 second, but writes everything during the first 0.5 second.

On average the write BW is 50%, but the FIFO needs to absorb 100% write traffic during the first 0.5 second. Therefore you must understand the patterns and the time frames to optimize the FIFO when using average BWs over long period of time.